# Array of Lists or Other Possibilities?

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list

So my question starts out as being is it possible to make an array of linked lists in Java?

For some background on why I am asking. I am working on a project in which we are given a file of square matrices. We have to find the determinant of the matrices but they have to be stored in a linked structure. We have previously done this same thing using arrays and so I can reuse a decent bit of my source from that one. Here is what I have though up to do (mostly based on my previous project):

1. Read each line of the file in as a string
2. Count the number of matrices and determine where each starts and ends.
3. * Read each element of each matrix into a multi-linked ListNode (I'll write the class for those)
4. * Repeat for each matrix
5. Process the determinant of each.

So the two starred steps are the ones I'm having a tough time figuring out. I want to read in all the matrices at once so I don't lose track of where I am in the file like I would if I read in one matrix, did the determinant, and then went back to the file to get another one. However, I don't know how to store each linked list representation so that I can just iteratively process through each. My only thought is to read each matrix into the linked list structure and store each linked list structure in an array if possible. If not possible, what is a possible alternative?

Comment: Sure--have you tried it?

Comment: If this is a homework or coursework assignment, please add the homework tag to this question.

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely possible to store an array of LinkedLists; arrays can be applied to objects as well as primitive types.  However, I would advise creating a Matrix class, because square matrices are not linked lists; they have data in two dimensions, not just one.  At the very least, you could use a two-dimensional array of floats to represent a matrix, and store a LinkedList of double[][]s.  The closer your representation is to the actual object, the easier it will be for you.

Comment: Thank you for the input with the array issue. The assignment was to use some form of linked list implementation. My plan is to use a multi-linked list so that each node will have a NextCol field which will be the link to the next node in a particular column and a NextRow field which will be the link to the next node in a particular row.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use the standard LinkedList class what java already has, the here is a possible implementation of reading, and storing your matrices:

```
int size = 10; //width and height of your matrix. 

LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>> matrix = new LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>>();

for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)
{
    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        //read the actual item
    }
    matrix.add(list);
}
```

For reading a matrix (probably numbers) i advise to use the class called Scanner. You can create a new Scanner, what will be able to read your file, number by number:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
```

And you can read integer values with it, without any conversion like this:

```
int x = sc.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an array of linked lists in Java by declaring LinkedList[], but if you do, your performance will suffer badly. A look at matrix multiplication will illustrate the reason.

If A and B are matrices where the A's column count equals B's row count, then A * B[r, c] is the dot product of row r in A with column c in B.  This means we have to extract rows and columns from our matrices.

If we form matrices from lists (of any sort), we can store them row-wise (i.e., where the 0-th list represents row 0), or column-wise (where the 0-th list represents column 0).

Now we run into a problem.  In a linked list, the method get(n) starts at the beginning of the list and finds the next member n times -- which makes it run in order n time.  A matrix built from linked lists will either extract columns very slowly (if stored row-wise), or extract rows very slowly (if stored column-wise).

I's suggest keeping it simple by using arrays of arrays.  You can allocate an n x n array with

int[][] values = new int[n][n];

The value 'n' must be defined, of course.

Hope that this helps.